# Equivalence of two definitions of connectivity of sets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

- We say that $U$ is **path-connected** if for every $x, y \in U$ there exists a path that connects them; i.e, if there exists a continuous function $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow U$ so that $\gamma (0)=x, \gamma (0)=y$.
  *(Intuitively, any two points in the set can be connected through the set)*.
- We sat that $U$ is **set-connected** if there are **no** open sets $A, B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ so that: 
  $U\subseteq A\cup B, \;  U\cap A \cap B = \varnothing,  \; U\cap A \neq \varnothing,  \; U\cap B \neq \varnothing $
  *(intuitively, these sets "seperate" $U$ to non-empty disjoint sets)*

I need to show that these to defintions are equavalent. I've shown that path-connectivity implies set-connectivity, so I need the other direction.

My idea was to try to divide $U$ into path-connected-components and show that there can be only one, but how can I show that?

I'd like to hear your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: You can't prove that, since the definitions are not equivalent (c.f. topologist's sine curve). However if you additionally assume that $U$ is open, they become equivalent. Just fix an element $u\in U$ and show that the set of elements that can be connected to $u$ with a path is open.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** [Topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).

**2nd Hint:** If $U$ is open they are equivalent, consider the points which are path-connected to some fixed point and the ones that are not.

Comment: Thank you! I indeed forgot that detail. Your 2nd hint helped.